# Keychain access to Microsot_Intermidiate_Certificates

Tags: macos, keychain

I need access to Microsoft Intermidiate Certificates in my Key Chain.

I unlocked the key chain using administrator password but still no access to the MIC.

It keeps asking me for a password (that I do not know), and it will not accept my admin password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password is blank for that keychain!

In the password window just hit Enter key without typing anything.

*I know it is a stupid thing to ask for a password that does not exist (unless it is set).

FYI, the Microsoft_Intermediate_Certificates keychain and the  Microsoft_Entity_Certificates) is used by MS Outlook for decryption of encrypted emails.*

Comment: WTH...did not think of that one :)